# Vim: brace matching unreliable

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim

I'm using Vim to edit JSP files with JavaScript. Somehow the % key (jump to matching brace) doesn't work most of the time: Sometimes it works, sometimes it works only in one direction, but most of the time it doesn't work at all. Of course Vim is able to highlight the right matching brace, but matchit.vim doesn't seem to find it. I'm using the latest version (1.13.2) of the plugin.

Example:

```
<s:layout-component name="extra_styles">
@import "${mediaPath}/css/whatever.css";
.test .someclassname {
    top: 5px;
    left: 32px;
}
</s:layout-component>
```

Here it won't find the matching curly brace.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Does anyone know the problem for this?

Comment: I added a small example.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem: % wouldn't jump to matching {}. This is my workaround:

```
:let b:match_debug=1
```

% starts dancing after that.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with the JSP syntax definition: I changed the filetype on your example to `css`: matchit jumps correctly from one curly brace to the other. Changing the filetype back to `jsp` makes matchit all dizzy.

`:set ft=css.jsp` seems to allow both the correct matchit behaviour and CSS omni-completion. See if it doesn't break anything on the jsp front.

Comment: Good try, but this breaks % tag matching for JSP and HTML tags.

Comment: I don't think matchit is supposed to work on pairs not being part of the language. Curly brackets are part of CSS but not part of JSP so matchit doesn't work its magic.